# What do you call a 'Nickname' that's longer than the actual name?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, names, nicknames

I'm pretty sure I used to know the term for a nickname that was longer or an expansion of a person's name.

EXAMPLE:  My name is Sunny but friends sometimes call me Sunshine.

Though longer, Sunshine is still a nickname since nicknames don't have to be shorter than the original.  But I'm sure there's a specialized term for this sort of reverse construction.  Help!

Comment: If you're prepared to accept, say, ***Mo*** as both a *nickname* and a ***diminutive*** of ***Maurice***, then note this citation from the full OED: *Compared with 'capello' = ‘a hat,’ the Italian word 'capellone' = ‘a great hat’ is an [**augmentative**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/augmentative).* My link there is to dictionary.reference.com, because most people won't be able to access subscriber-only OED.

Comment: That isn't really an antonym, though. The antonym of _nickname_ would be _real name_ or _proper name_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think you're getting close to the one I can't quite remember.  Like your suggestion, I think it took a nickname term (diminutive) and negated the root (augmentative).

Comment: @JohnLawler, +nod+ I cringed a little at my own title.  I wanted to use the term for "shorten a name" but I couldn't remember that one, either -- and I was afraid of sending myself into some sort of infinite loop of defining.

Comment: @JohnLawler ... +giggle+ ... I guess it would be a-not-so-infinite loop of defining ... finally landing in a pile of Semantic Primes:  'person', 'word', 'not', 'small'.

Comment: Short nicknames are called "Nicknames" Long nicknames are called "Nicholasnames"

Comment: Why would you expect a nickname that is longer than the name to have a special name? Do you also expect a nickname that is shorter than the name to have a special name?

Comment: You'd think it would be something like _Nicholasnicklebyname_, wouldn't you?

Comment: If you must have a different term, call it a "pet" name.

Comment: *Sunshine* is only longer than *Sunny* in writing; they're the same length (two syllables) when spoken. So there's another category of nickname for you to worry about.

Comment: Bon sang ! Mais c'est bien sur !

Comment: Diminutives can be longer than the original, for instance in Italian Paolo -> Paolino, or the same length such as Russian Ivan (Иван) -> Vanya (Ваня). Or in English, Smith -> Smithy, Nick -> Nicky.

Comment: This phenomenon (in general, not specifically for names) may be called “periphrasis”.

Comment: Nicknames are not defined by length....

Answer (score -1):

You may be thinking of

**Epithet:**
OED

> 2. A significant appellation.
>
> 1728   J. Morgan Compl. Hist. Algiers I. vi. 201   He assumed the proud Epithet of Sultan or Monarch of Tunis and all Barbary.

and [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/biography/William-I-king-of-Sicily)

> William I, byname William The Bad, ...Norman king of Sicily, .... His epithet was bestowed on him by his hapless enemies.